# Geometry.center() not applied

Tags: javascript, three.js

I got a BufferGeometry that I change vertices/colors on from time to time. I do this by creating a new buffergeometry if I need to allocate more space for vertices. If not, I will reuse the one I already have but changing drawRange of it.

My problem is that when I just update a BufferGeometry with new vertices as in the first "if(this.mesh != undefined && this.prev..." part of the code below, my geometry doesn't get center() anymore. Even though I explicitly apply it. If the geometry just need an update later it get's centered again. How can I solve this? (using the code below makes the object flickering between center() and non-center geometry position). Note that mesh.position has nothing to do with this, it's the same all the time.

```
if(this.mesh != undefined && this.prev_len > vertices.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
            this.v.setXYZ(i, vertices[i][0], vertices[i][1], vertices[i][2]);
            this.c.setXYZW(i, colors[i][0], colors[i][1], colors[i][2], 1);
        }
        this.geometry.setDrawRange(0, vertices.length); 
        this.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
        this.geometry.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;
        this.geometry.computeVertexNormals();

        // Here seems to be the problem. center() is not actually applied?
        // I've debuged three.js and it seems to perform the translate() in center() function. But it seems to be changed afterwards?
        this.mesh.geometry.center();

    } else {
        this.v = new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(vertices.length * 3), 3);
        this.c = new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(colors.length * 3), 3);
        for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
            this.v.setXYZ(i, vertices[i][0], vertices[i][1], vertices[i][2]);
            this.c.setXYZW(i, colors[i][0], colors[i][1], colors[i][2], 1);
        }
        this.geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
        this.geometry.dynamic = true;
        this.geometry.addAttribute('position', this.v);
        this.geometry.addAttribute('color', this.c);
        this.geometry.attributes.position.dynamic = true;
        this.geometry.attributes.color.dynamic = true;
        this.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
        this.prev_len = vertices.length;

        if(this.mesh == undefined) {
            this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);
            this.mesh.position.set(
                                   this.from_x,
                                   this.from_y,
                                   this.from_z
            );
            scene.add(this.mesh);
            this.geometry.center();

        } else {
            // This works fine, the geometry becomes centered.
            this.mesh.geometry = this.geometry; 
            this.geometry.center();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is center() is not applied to an geometry that has been updated with new positions. And calculation of a new center() for an updated BufferGeometry will create a false offset that's reflected by the changes to the position attribute.

My solution, that works, is to save the offset that is returned from geometry.center() and apply it for updated geometries.

```
this.offset = this.geometry.center();
```

Then apply it manually when just updating position, like this:

```
this.geometry.translate(this.offset.x, this.offset.y, this.offset.z);
```

Not sure if this is a "correct" solution or just a workaround. But works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You  modify "this.geometry" and then you apply "center()" to "this.mesh.geometry". Maybe it is a problem of broken reference between your BufferGeometry and the other attributes of your "this" object.

Comment: No, it's the same. But to be sure I tried to center() on this.geometry as well. But the issue remains.